# electric windows, fuel gauge,temp gauge,speedometer,rpm gauge all stopped working

Tags: toyota

my electric windows,speedomter,fuel gauge,temp gauge,rpm gauge, mile counter on my 1997 toyota camry suddenly stopped working and do not know why, checked all the fuses,and that the wiring is still connected

Comment: Welcome to the site. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you checked this, but it's almost certainly a fuse or the fuse connection. Looking at the fuse plan on [this site](http://www.autogenius.info/toyota-camry-1997-fuse-box-diagram/) your gauges on the binnacle and your power windows are all on fuse 21:

> Gauges and meters, back-up lights, cruise control system, charging
>   system, traction control system, daytime running light system, power
>   windows, service reminder indicators and warning buzzers

The fuse could have failed in a non-visible way, if you have a tester handy then by all means use it but if not just replace it, they are practically the cheapest thing on your car. It could be the fuse is fine and corrosion and/or gunk is fouling the contact between the fuse and the fuse clip. Replace that fuse and clean the contacts while you're at it.

EDIT: I thought it was worth adding that the fuse clip could be loose and not making good contact, you can usually tell this if the fuse pulls out easily on one side. You can often use a needle nose pliers to squeeze the fuse clips together to make a tighter connection. If a needle nose doesn't fit then 2 flat head glasses screwdrivers ought to do the trick.

Comment: Remember the fuse could be broken, not blown - blown is obvious burnt residue etc, but broken can look as if it is ok... need to test with a lamp or meter.

Comment: True, @SolarMike, I've edited to include that point and account for another, less common failure scenario.